# How to add table cell value in Google Slides using script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to update the value of a table cell in Google Slides using `Google App Script.`

Here is the code.

```js
function calculateResourceCapacity() {
  const FIXED_ROWS = 4;
  const COL_AVA_PD = 2;

  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();

  const monthPD = 24;
  const slide = presentation.getSelection().getCurrentPage();

  const elements = slide.getPageElements();
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    try {
      const table = elements[i].asTable();

      const cResource = table.getColumn(0);
      const lastRowIdx = cResource.getNumCells() - FIXED_ROWS;

      for (let i = 1; i <= lastRowIdx; ++i) {
        // This line fails to execute in Google Slides
        const cell = table.getCell(i, COL_AVA_PD).editAsText().setText(monthPD);
      }

      break;
    } catch(e) { }
  }
}
```

Unlike Google Docs, the `TableCell` object does not have `editAsText()` method in Google Slides.
Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-cell

What would be an ideal way for me to update a cell value in Google Slides using an App Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const cell = table.getCell(i, COL_AVA_PD).editAsText().setText(monthPD);
```

#### To:

```
const cell = table.getCell(i, COL_AVA_PD);
cell.getText().setText(monthPD);
```

#### References:

- [getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-cell#getText())
- [setText(newText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#setText(String))